# date as SEO optimization tool

Tags: php, html, date, seo

Consider the following PHP code for printing current date:

```
<!--Date as SEO optimization tool-->
<?php $today = date("F j, Y ");
echo '<span class="date">'.$today.'</span>';?>
```

Output is as follows: `November 29, 2011`
The pages on the site I'm working on are cached for 24 hours. Should I add `minutes and seconds` in terms of `better SEO`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better SEO, worse SEO. SEO is a myth, start doing something *real*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noone can tell for sure, but i would not believe it so.

I have never used anything more precise than the `Hours:Minutes` format, and my websites rank fine.